# Query format for NP without subject in PPCEME

Tags: corpora, research

As I, not being very familiar with corpus linguistics, read [the manual for searching through PPCEME](http://corpussearch.sourceforge.net/CS-manual/Contents.html) I entered:

```
node: NP*
print_indices: true
 query: (NP-SBJ *PRO*)
```

without getting a result.

Could anyone please give me a hint where my query is incorrect?

Comment: could you please edit your question and add what you expected to happen with that query?

Comment: from the title i'd guess finding NPs without subjects

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your query.  First of all, you need to escape the stars (with backslashes) or they will be interpreted as wildcards.  Second, pro-drop is indicated by `*pro*` (note lowercase).  Finally, you need to specify the query function.  You probably want this line:

```
query: (NP-SBJ iDominates \*pro\*)
```

Using `NP-SBJ*` as kaleissin suggested won't hurt, but it won't help with this issue either.

BTW, if you copied that query directly out of the manual, it is certainly a documentation bug.  If you can show me where specifically it came from, I can see that it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

[The manual](http://corpussearch.sourceforge.net/CS-manual/Tips.html#using_ast) I found states that you should be liberal with the use of *, so have you tried `NP-SBJ*`?