# Switchboard queries with NXT (the TEXT function)

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora

The NXT query language includes the query function [TEXT](http://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/nxt/nxtdoc/docquery_property_tests.xml), which should return the textual content of the variable it applies to. In theory, Switchboard should support this. The file README.SWBD-QUERIES.TXT, which comes with the [NXT Switchboard Annotations](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2009T26) download, recommends using TEXT to query the orthography:

> `($w word): (TEXT($w) == "the")`
>
> This is how to query the orthography.  Posix regular expressions work
>   here, too.
>
> `($w word): (TEXT($w) ~/the.*/)`

But this doesn't seem to work for word or phonword-type variables (works for phone-type variables though). There is no error message, just 0 results, so I'm guessing `TEXT($w)` just doesn't return anything. I know I can get around this by accessing the orthography attribute directly (`$w@orth ==` ...), but this won't work for non-terminals. So if I want to access the entire text under a certain non-terminal (which could dominate a number of terminals), there's no straightforward way of doing this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementation details of a particular software package, rather than linguistics.

Comment: Similar questions have been allowed in the past: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1790/query-format-for-np-without-subject-in-ppceme

Comment: Quite possibly. However, since there are lots of SEs with specific interests in individual software, I wonder whether it might be better answered on one of them.

Comment: The way I see it, the question is specific to the Switchboard annotations, not to the NXT toolkit. I would expect more linguists to be familiar with Switchboard than programmers/computer scientists.

Answer (score 2):

To get all orthography from non-terminals that dominate a WORD element, use the dominance operator; e.g.

```
($w word)($d da): ($d ^ $w) && ($w@orth ~ /the.*/)
```

or, if you prefer

```
($w word):($w@orth ~ /the.*/)::($d da): ($d ^ $w)
```

From memory, I think we made this design choice as a compromise to keep orthography from the phonetic and orthographic transcription separate for some kinds of queries.